# Identifying any gaps "broken span" in network of ducts using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I have a huge network of ducts and I need to identify if there are some gaps in the network, for example if some lines are not connected to each other in ArcGIS so I would like to select them.

I was using Selection by Location  by target the same layer using the method "touch the boundary of the source layer feature" and the result is not accurate.

[image: sample]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: Have you tried creating a database topology and applying a `Must Not Have Dangles` rule?

Comment: I was trying also topology and applying a must not have dangles  rule and there are to many errors (around 11454 and it's just for the test area) even if i'm adding also structure layer

Comment: @KirkKuykendall and next step?

Comment: How big are the gaps?  Have you considered snapping them? http://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/0412/use-the-snap-geoprocessing-tool-to-automate-editing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach to similar situations has been:

1. Identify and select a 'main' or some kind of starting point.  This should be a feature you want all the other features to be connected to.
2. Then use the 'Select by Location' tool to select other features from the same feature class that intersect the currently selected feature (the 'main'):
   [image: Image showing settings on select by location]
3. Then set your Table of Contents window to show you the number of currently selected features in the feature class:

[image: Showing TOC settings]

4. The trick is to then keep hitting the "Apply" button on the Select by Location Tool and watching the count of selected features.  It will increase every time you click "Apply" until you have selected all of the connected features.

If you want to know about *disconnected* features, then open the attribute table for your feature class and hit the "Switch Selection" button on the top of the pane.  That will select any features that ARE NOT connected to the 'Main' feature you selected in step one.

This can also be done with Python, you just need to count the selected features every time you re-run the selection and test to see if it has increased or not.

Comment: I was trying in this morning also your method but it's not really accurate and I cannot make a report to say the for a small test area you need to hit apply 6th times... for the moment for answer is the best one... thx.

Comment: I would write it in python if you need to report on it.  Build a loop that runs the selection, counts the selected features, and runs the selection again and counts them again.  If the number has increased, continue.  If not, compare the number of selected features to the total count.  Then you could say that X of Y pieces are connected to each other for a given set.  That would at least be more interesting than saying "I had to press the button 5 times before it stopped."